# Pandas style.hide() is trying to escape the quotes in variable provided

Tags: python, pandas, hide

I am making a basic mistake here. I need to programmatically pre-create the string of all columns to be hidden [This is due to the behaviour of [pandas style.hide()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html), specifically the following from the specs: "*...The specified data rows/columns are hidden, but the axis-Index itself, and names, remain unchanged*". It does not let me hide 1 column at a time].
Below is a simplified working example but in reality I have a multi-index column in which I need to hide certain child columns across multiple parent levels. The issue is that hide() does not have a 'escape=False' parameter so it does not escape the quotes in the string I provide, 'str_hide'. I am sure this is a 1-minute fix using some string operation...hence the 'basic mistake' part of my question. Could you please advise how to make the second part work? Thanks.

```
#Init
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])

#This works
# sdf = df.style.hide(['A', 'B'], axis='columns')

#This does not work
str_hide = "\'A\', \'B\'"
print(str_hide)  #Looks the same as above but is interpreted differently below
sdf = df.style.hide([str_hide], axis='columns')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column names are not `'A'` and `'B'`, they are `A` and `B`. So you can simplify:

```
str_hide = "A,B"
sdf = df.style.hide(str_hide.split(','), axis='columns')
```

Comment: Nick, thanks for pointing out my mistake! Realizing my error, I simplified my code to not create a string at all and just added the col names in a list to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape splitted values:

```
#test
print ([ord(x) for x in ['A', 'B']])
[65, 66]

print([ord(x.strip("\' ")) for x in str_hide.split(',')]) 
[65, 66]

sdf = df.style.hide([x.strip("\' ") for x in str_hide.split(',')], axis='columns')
```

Comment: @Anand - OK, can you explain how accepted solution working with `str_hide = "\'A\', \'B\'"` ?

Comment: jezrael, it was per Nick's comment, "Your column names are not 'A' and 'B', they are A and B", that made me realize that going about creating a string is the error. So instead of creating and then parsing a string that superficially looked like the column names (per my original code) I now do lHideCols.append((col,'KPI_Name')) in a loop, where col is a variable and I hide 'KPI Name' in a columnar multi-index. Then needing to escape quotes in a string does not enter the equation at all. His code also works. Thank you for taking the time though; it is much appreciated.